# How can i disable the touch bar functionality in Mac through Objective C or Java

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, macos-sierra, macbookpro-touch-bar

http://www.imore.com/how-disable-touch-bar-macbook-pro-so-you-can-take-your-exams

This blog talks about disabling the new touch bar on a mac book pro by user.

Can achieve the same by using Objective C or JAVA?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can achieve this by setting the NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled boolean value to No.

defaults write com.apple.systemuiserver NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled -bool NO

You can do the same in objective c by

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:myDict];
```

Source: http://indiestack.com/2016/12/touch-bar-crash-protection/